# How to get Exam_name(Quarterly, Half-yearly, Final) wise total obtained marks for each student?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, pivot

I have a table like this.
Table:-

```
ID  Name            Exam_name   Marks
1   Abhinaba Modak  Quarterly   17
1   Abhinaba Modak  Quarterly   18
1   Abhinaba Modak  Half Yearly 66
1   Abhinaba Modak  Half Yearly 69
1   Abhinaba Modak  Final       85
1   Abhinaba Modak  Final       84
12  Soumen Roy      Quarterly   14
12  Soumen Roy      Quarterly   14
12  Soumen Roy      Half Yearly 57
12  Soumen Roy      Half Yearly 60
12  Soumen Roy      Final       78
12  Soumen Roy      Final       77
```

I need to run a query to get an output of Exam_name(Quarterly, Half-yearly, Final) wise total obtained marks for each student.
Expected Output:-

```
Name             Quarterly  Half Yearly    Final
Abhinaba Modak   35         135            169
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    name,
    sum(case when exam_name = 'Quaterly' then marks end) quarterly,
    sum(case when exam_name = 'Half Yearly' then marks end) half_yearly,
    sum(case when exam_name = 'Final' then marks end) final
from mytable
group by name
```